# Fetch max value column with row cells condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table :

```
 Name  |   value
-------+-----------
     A | 1
     B | 2
     A | 3
     B | 4
     C | 5
     D | 6
```

For each record, I want the max value according to the name like that :

```
 Name  |   value | maxvalue
-------+---------+----------
     A | 1       | 3
     B | 2       | 4
     A | 3       | 3
     B | 4       | 4
     C | 5       | 5
     D | 6       | 6
```

What is the most efficient way to do it with python ?
Ì have tables, some with few records (~100 lines), and some tables with huge records (>1billion)

Thanks a lot guys !

Comment: `df.groupby("Name").agg("max")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not been enough precise : I want to add this value to each row in the new column

Comment: What libraries are you using? (Tag your question with them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that there's a slightly faster way, but here's an example with `pandas`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"name": list("ABABCD"), "value": np.arange(6)})
maxes = df.groupby("name").agg("max")
df["maxvalue"] = df["name"].apply(lambda x: maxes.loc[x])
```

```
>>> df
  name  value  maxvalue
0    A      0         2
1    B      1         3
2    A      2         2
3    B      3         3
4    C      4         4
5    D      5         5
```